# how to create a sub domain outside google cloud and have hosting for the sub domain inside google cloud vm instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The website example.com is hosted with bluehost(with cpanel) and the domain is registered with a different service provider. How do i create a sub domain(web.example.com) for example.com and have it point to the hosting (for the sub domain alone) in google cloud vm instance(ubuntu 16.04) running LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have hosted your main domain through cpanel, updating the DNS records there will give you the solution. You can follow the below steps

1. Login to cpanel.
2. Add an “A” record  web.example.com with IP address of the LAMP stack VM running in Google cloud.

You can find details on adding a record in cpanel [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Advanced+Zone+Editor)

On a side note, if you are using an Ephemeral IP for your LAMP Stack VM you might risk getting a new IP if your instance shuts down which will require a change in the configuration, therefore having a static IP is recommended. Keep in mind that [static IPs are free of charge](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) as long as they are assigned.

Comment: thank you, can something like this be done at the "Manage DNS" at where the domain is registered with and not at the hosted cpanel ? if possible how ?

Comment: May I know where did you purchased your domain from?

Comment: its from net4.com

Comment: I can only see this option in their customer care management page [1]. Select "Service Type" as "Domain" and "Problem Type" as "A record Change" , then fill the personal fields and submit.                                                                                                   

        [1] http://www.net4.com/aspx/general/customer-care.aspx